# If "discuss about" is redundant, what about "discuss with you about"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

My research showed that "discuss about" is incorrect because "discuss" is a transitive verb which means an object have to be attached. So "discuss about" would be redundant as in "talk about about".

But what if I say "discuss with you about"? Is it still redundant in this case or are there other problems?

For example:

> "I want to discuss with you about logistics"

I know the best version would be:

> "I want to discuss logistics with you"

But is the first version still wrong? Thanks

Comment: The first version is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> ✘ I want to discuss with you about logistics.

That sentence is ungrammatical.

---

What you could say is:

> ✔ I want to *have a discussion* with you about logistics.

---

The only way I can think of to use both *discuss* and *about* in a grammatical way is the following:

> I want to discuss something about logistics with you.

However, while the sentence is fine, it's slightly unnatural sounding and would not normally be used instead of the simpler *discuss logistics*.

Answer (score 0):

English tends to aim for as few words as possible. 
What do you want to discuss? Logic.
With whom? You.

"About" is implied so it is redundant.